# Which drawable folder does a high density phone default to?

Tags: android, android-image, android-resources

If I have an extra-high-quality image in the `drawable-xhdpi` folder and a medium-quality image with the same name in the `drawable-mdpi`, which of the two would a high density phone use?

> **Edit 1:** Nanne's answer does *not* answer my question. His quoted passage relates to screen *size* whereas my question relates to screen
>   *density*. I followed the link provided by Nanne (thanks Nanne) and did
>   find this useful passage however:
>
> *"... you do not need default drawable resources when you provide
>   alternative drawable resources with the screen density qualifier. Even
>   without default drawable resources, Android can find the best match
>   among the alternative screen densities and scale the bitmaps as
>   necessary..."*
>
> But!! it just says (vaguely) Android will find the best match. Anyone
>   know what that best match would be as per my question?
>
> **Edit 2:** A bit of background on Nanne's request: I have a project to which I have added medium, high and extra-high density versions of
>   images. My apk size is now ever so slightly over 20MB and I would like
>   to keep it below 20MB. I would like to remove some images from either
>   the mdpi, hdpi or xhdpi folder in a way that images still scale
>   and look ok on all density phones, but am not sure which folder to
>   remove some of the images from...

Comment: Can you add what problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

From [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch)

> When selecting resources based on the screen size qualifiers, the
>   system will use resources designed for a screen smaller than the
>   current screen if there are no resources that better match (for
>   example, a large-size screen will use normal-size screen resources if
>   necessary). However, if the only available resources are larger than
>   the current screen, the system will not use them and your application
>   will crash if no other resources match the device configuration (for
>   example, if all layout resources are tagged with the xlarge qualifier,
>   but the device is a normal-size screen).

So it should use the medium one.